# Chromedriver for v121 (no chromedriver.exe)

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

There is no chromedriver.exe file in my latest driver (v121). I'm getting like the below image when I try to open the driver file.

[image]

Suggest me the solution for this problem.

Comment: I see it chromedriver.exe after downloading from `https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/121.0.6167.184/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip`. I think you tried downloading from the other URL, which is for the Chrome browser, not for the ChromeDriver.